# Mac App Store entitlement - code object is not signed at all

Tags: macos, mac-app-store, codesign, entitlements

I've been trying to submit an app update to the Mac OSX Store but all my submissions have been rejected with the error "code object is not signed at all"

I've been code signing the entitlements like this:

```
codesign -f -v -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: My Company (XXXXXXXXXX)" MyApp.app/Contents/entitlements.plist
codesign -f -v -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: My Company (XXXXXXXXXX)" MyApp.app
codesign -f -v -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application: My Company (XXXXXXXXXX)" --entitlements MyApp.app/Contents/entitlements.plist MyApp.app
```

If I then do the following:

```
codesign --display --entitlements - MyApp.app
```

I get the contents of the entitlements files along with some unusual characters:

```
??qq%<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
        <true/>
        <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
```

Which suggests that the entitlements are code signed and displaying correctly.

I've tried RB App Checker Lite which says everything is fine but when I try using spctl:

```
spctl --assess --type execute MyApp.app
```

I get :

```
MyApp.app: rejected
```

I'm not too sure where to go from here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if thats the same as is was for me, but I needed to remove the entitlements file from the app bundle and sign it along with the bundle like that:

```
codesign -f -s "3rd Party Mac Developer Application" -v "DA-FormMaker.app" —-deep --entitlements Entitlements.plist
```

I used Delphi XE4 and in the past the entitlements file was placed in the bundle by Delphi.

I removed Entitlements.plist from the bundle and signed it. After that the app was acceptet.

Andy